# Problema com acentuações e caracteres especias, na chamada Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, funções, codificação-de-caracteres

tenho uma função que faz uma chamada ajax, e manda os dados para serem salvos no banco, o problema é que sempre que salva uma palavra que tem algum caractere especial ou acentuação, não codifica da maneira correta,

ja tentei usar o :

```
encodeURIComponent(string)
```

pórem não mostrou o resultado experado, minha função esta da seguinte maneira

```
function relatorio() {

    var tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "relatorio.asp",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data: {
            tipo: encodeURIComponent(tipo) , exs: "relatorio_tipo"
        }
    });
}
```

se eu mando um tipo = "função"
salva no banco da seguinte maneira = "fun&231&227o"

não sei se estou fazendo da maneira correta ou se está faltando algo
gostaria de saber uma solução para que minha variável seja salva da maneira correta.

codigo que esta no relatorio.asp

```
if ex = "relatorio_tipo" then

Response.Charset="ISO-8859-1"
tipo= trata_sql(request("tipo"))

 set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 rs.LockType = 2
 rs.Open "relatorios", conexao
 rs.addnew
 rs("tipo") = tipo
 rs("data") = now()
 rs.Update

rs.close
set rs = nothing
conexao.close
set conexao = nothing

end if
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados?
Pode ser a codificação do bando de dados que não está aceitando caracteres especiais Ou tente passar isso o charset como iso
'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'

Comment: o banco é o mysql, eu percebi que no data:{ tipo: encodeURIComponent(tipo)} a variavel nao codifica, quando dou um print pra ver o que esta trazendo não retorna da maneira correta, tentei usar Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 e o problema ainda continuo  e o tipo ficou igual = fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Pode ser que o problema seja no banco mesmo, você consegue pegar a string encoded e fazer um insert direto na tabela para ver se salva corretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade é remover o `encodeURIComponent`, acredito que não terá a necessidade de utilizar o encodeURIComponent nesse seu cenário, pois o AJAX está utilizando o método **POST**, seu o método fosse **GET** seria interessante utilizar o encodeURIComponent, entretanto terá a necessidade de usar uma função para o decode no asp.

```
function relatorio() {

    var tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "relatorio.asp",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data: {
            tipo: tipo
        }
    });
}
```

E no seu arquivo `relatorio.asp` alterar o Charset incluido no inicio do arquivo o comando `Response.Charset="UTF-8"`

Comment: tentei desta maneira tambem e infelizmente não resolveu o problema, no banco salva exatamente a maneira que a variavel esta carregando,, por exemplo se eu der um alert() na variavel tipo antes  do data: {
            tipo: encodeURIComponent(tipo)
        }     ele traz a variavel da maneira certa "função"  e dentro do data a variável tipo já carrega de forma diferente  "fun&231&227o"  , tentei varias possibilidades e ainda não consegui compreender o motivo

Comment: @Jess vc removeu o encodeURIComponent ??

Comment: eu tentei com ele e sem também

Comment: @Jess tem como postar seu código relatorio.asp

Comment: e percebi que com o encodeURIComponent ele traz a variavel dessa maneira  "fun&231&227o" e sem ele fica do mesmo jeito, é como se não tivesse fazendo diferença ele la

Comment: atualizei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo que tenho no relatorio.asp que é referente a função

Comment: troque Response.Charset="ISO-8859-1" por Response.Charset="UTF-8"

Comment: fiz a troca e continua o problema

Comment: no relatorio.asp , estou tando um response.write na variavel tipo antes de fazer o create e vem sempre da mesma maneira   "fun&231&227o"

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui finalmente resolver este problema, para quem estiver tendo um problema parecido  o que fiz foi o seguinte:

```
function relatorio() {

    var tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
```

primeiro eu fiz um encodeURIComponent() da variavel tipo

```
t = encodeURIComponent(tipo); 

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "relatorio.asp",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    data: {
     //aqui eu fiz um decodeURIComponent(t) 
       tipo: decodeURIComponent(t) , exs: "relatorio_tipo"
    }
});
```

}

desta maneira o problema resolve.